# Read and Write data with Open layers 3

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango, openlayers-3

I am currently using postGIS/geoDjango/OL3

I need the capability for a user to drop a point on the map, and store that in my database.

When any user returns, that point will be shown on the map.

I thought I could do this with geoJSON format and just write to it every time the user drops a point.

Is there a tutorial for doing this operation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [django-floppyforms](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-floppyforms/blob/master/docs/geodjango.rst). it provides fields and rich widgets for easy manipulation of GEOS geometry fields.

Also read [this](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/edit-django-geometries-fields-with-leaflet.html).

Comment: I've seen this before, But still I did not use it. sorry dude.